# 20.04 - Can't boot after updating graphics card driver

Tags: boot, drivers, 20.04, data-recovery

My problems started when I booted up today and my resolution was limited to 1024x768. To fix it I tried another driver for the graphics card (Nvidia GeForce gtx650), but as a result now the computer won't boot. Any ideas about how I can fix it?

I don't really have any files that I need to save so I could just try and re-install Ubuntu. But perhaps another version is more stable than 20.04?

Comment: What version driver did you install? Boot to Recovery Mode, Root Access, from the GRUB menu, and uninstall the (Nvidia/other) driver. `sudo dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii` then `sudo apt-get purge package_name`.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Dang, I don't remember exactly what was the name of the driver. I guess I need it to run that command